# Sending data from ajax to php return NULL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to send data from ajax to php.

When I´m trying to alert it, it works perfectly, but when i tried to post the data it didnt work.

My Ajax

```
function onBtnClick(event){
    var nah = JSON.stringify(points);
    alert(nah);
    $.ajax( {
      url:"../php/points.php",
      type:'post',
      data: {point:nah},
      success: function(response){
          window.location = "../php/points.php";
      }

  })

  }
```

Points that im trying to post

```
 points[currentid] = {id: currentid, x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY};
  currentid++;
```

Php Code

```
if(isset($_POST['point'])){
        $user = $_POST['point'];

        $decoded = json_decode($user, true);

        var_dump($decoded);

        echo $decoded;
    }
```

Comment: Have you opened the developer tools in the browser? Are there error? Have you watched the request/response in the network tab?

Comment: I think you are missing some context. Specifically where is the code of points.php? And why would an alert show something that is being posted as alert is js and the post is handle by php.

Comment: In Console there is no error and in my network tab it the last thing it shows is this 
  https://imgur.com/a/KCoBRTr  nothing about post or something like that.

Comment: does the callback function fire at all? look in the network tab of developer tools to watch specifically the XHR requests

Comment: _Side note:_ Why are you stringify:ing the data before sending it? Just do: `data: {point: points}` and you won't need to decode it in PHP. jQuery will handle the serialization for you.

Comment: I'm also guessing that `$decoded` is an array, which would mean that `echo $decoded;` would throw a "Array to string conversion"-notice since you can't echo an array.

Comment: In XHR tab is nothing.

Comment: What happens when you call your function? Does it alert `nah` and then nothing at all? Have you checked for errors in the console? Also, just to make sure, when it comes to the network tab, you sometimes need to have it open before you make the ajax call or it won't show up.

Comment: Are you using proxy server like nagnix or varnish or cache plugins. If there's no error in log so I think your script run fine And the problem in server side request.

Comment: `nah` shows me every point in that array but it never send to php.

Comment: I do not use proxy servers.